# What optimisation is safe that still allows -assumenosideeffects removals

Tags: android, proguard

I've noticed that with projects I have created recently, there comes a new approach to proguard which is to use a pre-built script:

> ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

This is without optimisation, and comes with a comment:

> Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
>   through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
>   of these optimizations on its own).

It appears that following this advice means that `assumenosideeffects` has no effect. For example, these common tasks:

```
#Remove logging
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

#Remove asserts
-assumenosideeffects class junit.framework.Assert {
  public static *** assert*(...);
}
```

Proof it's not working:

```
if (release)
{
    Assert.assertTrue("Proguard config error, Asserts have been left in", false);
}
```

Is there a safe middle ground, where I can apply optimisation to trim out debug as defined with `assumenosideeffects`, but without risking the associated problems with Dex and proguard optimisation?

Answer (score 3):

The solution that I have found is to explicitly only enable the optimizations that the `assumenosideeffects` command depends on. So an example proguard config would be the following:

```
# proguard-project.txt

# Remove all Verbose/Debug logging
-optimizations code/removal/simple,code/removal/advanced
-dontobfuscate
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int v(...);
    public static int d(...);
}
```

Note that the project.properties file should specify the **optimize** SDK proguard config file, since a single call to `-dontoptimize` disables optimizations.

```
# project.properties

proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```